# Error:Cannot find type System.MarshalByRefObject in module CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary in windows universal platform aoo for windows 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, frameworks, windows-10

Hello i am working on windows universal platform app in this app 
the  error is occured when i Debug my windows universal project this error comes automatically so any one suggest me how resolve this error?

Error : -  Cannot find type System.MarshalByRefObject in module CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary

so suggest me how to resolve this error.

Comment: You have confuse web programming with windows-10 and aoo apps - this two are two different animals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have resolved this error while removing **System.Drawing** reference from Windows 10 Universal app project.

As on search <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> all keyword system.drawling not found in solution. because this reference only added to project and not in use. so checked in project file **.csproj** which find it. and remove this reference.

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml">
      <HintPath>..\JOIN8POS.Website\SharedDLL\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Drawing.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

and save .csproj file and reload all.

[image]

Comment: Just had the same error, the refference was imported automatically so I needed some time to get to this post. Ty for your post :)

Comment: Yes you can, and let me know